# How can we pass topic and subscription name from yaml in azure function - java

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, kubernetes-helm

```
@FunctionName("TestHandler")
public void Handler(
   @ServiceBusTopicTrigger(
           name = "ServiceBus",
           topicName = "topicname",
           connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString",
           subscriptionName = "subscriptionName")
       String message,
   final ExecutionContext context) {}
```

I want to fetch subscriptionName  value from deployment.yaml , config map settings. How can I get the value from there.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible AFAIK.

---

This is a Function setting and can only be specified in `function.json`, which in case of Java is *generated* and not written by you. So it must be in code.

There are some exceptions where you can specify a special value in code, which refers to app settings (e.g. see SheduleExpression [for timer trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#configuration)). But I don't see anything similar in Service Bus binding.

You can give it a try by specifying `subscriptionName = "%MY_SUBSCRIPTION_CONFIG%"` in annotation/code and add `MY_SUBSCRIPTION_CONFIG` to app settings (via `local.settings.json` or whatever) and see if it works.

Else reach out to Azure Support to confirm one way or the other.

Comment: I tried but it takes it as "subscriptionName" : "%subscriptonFb%"  and not the actual value

Comment: Unfortunate I guess. What happens if you remove `subscriptionName` altogether OR set it to `""`? I'm thinking `ServiceBusConnectionString` would be sufficient to connect and wouldn't need to know `subscriptionName`. And it can be externalized.